# Are all or some of the characters named Sganarelle the same person?

Tags: character-analysis, french-language, moliere

A recurring name in the cast of Molière's plays is named Sganarelle. If they were all the same person, the story of his life would look something like this:

- *The Flying Doctor*: Sganarelle is a servant to Valère
- *Dom Juan*: Sganarelle is a servant to Dom Juan and apparently unmarried
- *The School For Husbands*: Sganarelle is supposed to marry Isabella, but she ends up marrying someone else
- *The Forced Marriage*: Sganarelle is "52 or 53" years old and is forced to promise to marry Dorimène who is actually in love with Lycaste
- *Sganarelle, or The Imaginary Cuckold*: Sganarelle is married and he and his unnamed wife suspect each other of cheating on each other
- *The Doctor Despite Himself*: Sganarelle is married to Martine and they fight with each other before she takes revenge on him
- *Love the Doctor*: Sganarelle's wife is dead and he has a daughter whom he doesn't want to let marry

All of the plays in which Sganarelle is married show him and his wife fighting (*Sganarelle*  *The Doctor Despite Himself* act 1, scene 1) and he attests to that fact after her death (*Love the Doctor*, act 1, scene 1). Every Sganarelle also seems to have similar mannerisms: For example, his fanciful quotations of Aristotle and philosophers (*The Doctor in Spite of Himself* act 1, scene 1; *Dom Juan* act 1, scene 1; *Love the Doctor* act 1, scene 1) and his intense fear of being cuckolded (throughout every play in which he appears, with the possible exceptions of *The Flying Doctor* and *Dom Juan*). In addition, they both seem to live close enough to a place where non-standard French is spoken (*Dom Juan* act 2; *The Doctor in Spite of Himself*).

While some of his potential spouses seem to have different names (indeed in *Love the Doctor* act 1, scene 1 he says he only had one wife), the only named one he is shown as having actually married is Martine.

Is there any evidence that some *or* all of these characters named Sganarelle were or weren't intended to be the same person?